# effect of replacing @Controller with@RestController in spring

Tags: java, spring

Can we replace `@Controller` with `@RestController` or vice versa, what will be the impact on application.

Answer (score 2):

In simple word `@Controller` is Spring MVC annotation and while using `@Controller` you need to add @ResponseBody` for each requestmapping

Example:

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("employees")
 public class EmployeeController {
 Employee employee = new Employee();
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
 public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployeeInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
   employee.setName(name);
   employee.setEmail("employee1@genuitec.com");
 return employee; 
    }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
 public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployeeInXML(@PathVariable String name)  {
   employee.setName(name);
  employee.setEmail("employee1@genuitec.com");
   return employee; 
   }
}
```

Spring 4.0 introduced `@RestController`, a specialized version of the controller which is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than add the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations. By annotating the controller class with `@RestController` annotation, you no longer need to add `@ResponseBody` to all the request mapping methods.

Example :

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("employees")
 public class EmployeeController {
 Employee employee = new Employee();
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
 public Employee getEmployeeInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
   employee.setName(name);
   employee.setEmail("employee1@genuitec.com");
   return employee;
 }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
 public Employee getEmployeeInXML(@PathVariable String name) {
   employee.setName(name);
   employee.setEmail("employee1@genuitec.com");
 return employee; 
   } 
 }
```

So finally conclusion if you want to replace `@RestController` with `@Controller` you need to explicitly add `@ResponseBody` to all your request mappings

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, @RestController is @Controller + @ResponseBody. So if you are using latest spring version you can directly replace @Controller with @RestController without any issue.

But if you have to replace @RestController with @Controller then you will have to add @ResponseBody tag explicitly. Combination of @Controller + @ResponseBody would work in all versions of spring